# How to strictly set size for a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, function, size, strlen

In PHP, there is a function, called `settype` which is used to set type of a variable. I know we can define conditions for size of a variable using functions like `strlen`. But actually, I wanna know is there a function like `settype` to set size for a variable in PHP? something like this:

```
setsize($var, 10);  #for example: size of $var is equal to 10 characters.
```

Comment: As far as I am aware you would have to create them, you can certainly type hint a function, but as far as I know I couldn't specify a string of 10 characters (at least in the function signature) the only thing I can think of right now that sound even close is array_pad and str_pad combined with, as you mentioned, comparisons like strlen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Actually there is no Setsize native function in PHP.** to answer your question.
In fact the definition of size can be ambiguous as used in your question.The size can refer to **quantity of memory allocated for a variable**.If we refer to this definition **there is absolutely no way to set a fixed size directly in PHP for a single variable**.The size can also refer to the length of a variable when we talk about string or array or to the number of digit in a number.In this case too there is **no native way to specify a fixed length**.
However You can achieve this using **custom function or class** .

In fact we already got an example in PHP natively but only for arrays, the [SPLFixedArray class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php) which like its name indicate allows us to handle fixed length of arrays.

So if your desire is just about length you can build a class or a function to handle assignation and thus control the length of your variable yourself.But any assignation without this class/function will not prevent a variable length of data...:
example:

```
class fixedLength{
    protected $data,$length;
    public function __construct($data,$length){
        if(!is_int($length)) 
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('the length must be an integer ,'.gettype($length).' given');
        $this->length=$length;
        if(is_array($data))
        {
            while(count($data)>$length)
            {
                array_pop($data); 
            }
             $this->data=$data;
        }
        elseif(is_string($data))
        {
            $this->data=substr($data,0,$length);
        }
        elseif(is_int($data))
        {
            $this->data=(int)substr(strval($data),0,$length);
        }
        elseif(is_float($data))
        {
            $this->data=(float)substr(strval($data),0,$length);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Can\'t handle '.gettype($data).' type');
            
        }

    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return strtolower($name)==='data'?$this->data:false;    
    }

    public function __set($name,$value)
    {
        if(strtolower($name)!=='data')
            return false;   
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            while(count($value)>$this->length)
            {
                array_pop($value); 
            }
            $this->data=$value;
        }
        elseif(is_string($value))
        {
            $this->data=substr($value,0,$this->length);
        }
        elseif(is_int($value))
        {
            $this->data=(int)substr(strval($value),0,$this->length);
        }
        elseif(is_float($value))
        {
            $this->data=(float)substr(strval($value),0,$this->length);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Can\'t handle '.gettype($value).' type');       
        }
        
    }

}
```

Then in your code you can do:

```
$int=new fixedLength(98565,3);//will keep 985
$int->data=189999;// will keep 189
var_dump($int->data);//output 189
```

of course this example is really basic as it only handle assignation.In case of array you could implement the `ArrayAccess`
interface but you  must respect the same logic in the different functions which try to assign a value to data.